# Reset igx-select

Tags: drop-down-menu, igx-grid

Since I could not find any information, I am writing here.
How can I reset a selected value of igx-select using typescript:

[image]

Here is my HTML-Code:

```
        <igx-select #selectDepartment
             placeholder="Wähle Abteilung"
             [overlaySettings]="overlaySettings"
             [ngClass]="[cell.row.deleted?'upfont' : 'drop-down-grid']"
             [(ngModel)]="cell.value">
         <igx-select-item style="font-size: 12px;" *ngFor="let item of arrayDepartments" [value]="item">
           {{ item }}
         </igx-select-item>
       </igx-select>
```

Is there any way to delete the value of the cell and show the placeholder when for example a button is clicked?

Comment: This is the API documentation that lists all available properties, methods and events. clearSelection() is one of them:
https://www.infragistics.com/products/ignite-ui-angular/docs/typescript/latest/classes/IgxSelectComponent.html#clearSelection

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `clearSelection` method exposed by the `IgxSelectComponent`.

```html
<igx-select #selectDepartment
     placeholder="Wähle Abteilung"
     [overlaySettings]="overlaySettings"
     [ngClass]="[cell.row.deleted?'upfont' : 'drop-down-grid']"
     [(ngModel)]="cell.value">
 <igx-select-item style="font-size: 12px;" *ngFor="let item of arrayDepartments" [value]="item">
   {{ item }}
 </igx-select-item>
</igx-select>
<button igxButton (click)="reset(selectDepartment)">Reset</button>
```

```js
public reset(select: IgxSelectComponent) {
    select.clearSelection();
}
```

[Here's a stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wgdrwb?file=src/app/select-sample-1/select-sample-1.component.ts).